# HTML and ejs Tags Messed Up After Save

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I am pretty new to coding and learning templating at the moment. I am having trouble with html and ejs tags auto formatting after save.

As you can see in the images below (sorry, cannot embed images on the post yet since I am new here), html and ejs tags get separated after saving the file and it looks ugly. How can I prevent them from separating?

Saving also auto-indents codes after ejs tags... I want to use format on save, but don't want the indentation.

'Files:Associations' setting already has '*.ejs - html'.
'Emmet: Include Languages' setting also has 'ejs - html'.
'Editor: Default Formatter' is set to None.
Extensions I have are 'EditorConfig for VS Code' and 'EJS language support'

***Code Before Save:***

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Browsing The <%= name %> subreddit</h1>
        <h2><%= description %></h2>
        <p><%= subscribers %> Total Subscribers</p>
        <hr>
        
        <% for(let post of posts) { %>
            <article>
                <p><%= post.title %> - <b><%=post.author %></b></p>
                <% if(post.img) { %>
                    <img src="<%= post.img %>" alt="">
                    <% } %>
            </article>
            <% } %>
    </div>
</body>
```

***Code After Save:***
(for example, the bold tag looks out of place and I also want p and b tags in one line along with the ejs tags)

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Browsing The <%= name %> subreddit</h1>
        <h2>
            <%= description %>
        </h2>
        <p>
            <%= subscribers %> Total Subscribers
        </p>
        <hr>

        <% for(let post of posts) { %>
            <article>
                <p>
                    <%= post.title %> - <b>
                            <%=post.author %>
                        </b>
                </p>
                <% if(post.img) { %>
                    <img src="<%= post.img %>" alt="">
                    <% } %>
            </article>
            <% } %>
    </div>
</body>
```

***Indentation on Save - After ejs Tags***

```
<%- include('partials/head') %>
  <%- include('partials/head') %>

    <body>
      <%- include('partials/navbar') %>

        <h1>Your random number is: <%= num %>
        </h1>

        <% if (num % 2===0) { %>
          <h2>That is an even number!</h2>
          <% } else { %>
            <h2>That is an odd number!</h2>
            <% } %>
              <h3>
                <%= num % 2===0 ? 'Even' : 'Odd' %>
              </h3>
    </body>

    </html>
```

[BeforeSave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9Tkg.png)

[AfterSave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRG3E.png)

[Files: Associations setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4dAy.png)

[Emmet: Include Languages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9Gxi.png)

Comment: Welcome to the community. Please post code instead of images so that it's easier for us to test your code

Comment: @SaulMartinez Sorry, I included my code. Thanks!